# TypeScript compile-time constants?

Tags: typescript

I'm writing a library in TypeScript and I want to target both Node and Browser. Right now I'm running `tsc` twice with two different targets. That part is working OK.

However, a tiny portion of my code is target-specific. I need to be able to do something like:

```
if(BUILD_TARGET === 'node') {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

Is there any way I can inject these constants at compile-time so that they can either be optimized away by `tsc` itself, or via a pass through UglifyJS (or some such tool)?

Comment: You can check for the presence of the `window` object which will be there in the browser but not in node

Comment: @NitzanTomer That might solve a few scenarios, but I still want something that can be precompiled away.

Comment: You may check this project https://github.com/itsdouges/ts-transform-define to define global consts at compile-time. It uses the TTypescript transformer project
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ttypescript

Answer (score 15):

The closest thing to compile-time constants in typescript are `const enums` - according to the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#const-enums), "unlike regular enums they are completely removed during compilation".

This [comes at a price however](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#const-enum-pitfalls) - the biggest caveat is that const enums are incompatible with `isolatedModules = true` mode which is often used by bundlers.

Also, Typescript won't do dead code elimination, you will have to use some other tool to remove `if (0 === 1)` branch afterwards.

You will need two different `tsconfig.json` files, each will include a file that will have a different definition for the same enum type.

**tsconfig.browser.json**

```
{
  "files": [
    "t.ts",
    "target-enum-browser.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

**target-enum-browser.d.ts**

```
declare module 'target-enum' {
    export const enum Target { Node, Browser, Current = Browser }
}
```

**tsconfig.node.json**

```
{
  "files": [
    "t.ts",
    "target-enum-node.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

**target-enum-node.d.ts**

```
declare module 'target-enum' {
    export const enum Target { Node, Browser, Current = Node }
}
```

**t.ts**

```
import {Target} from 'target-enum';

if (Target.Current === Target.Browser) {
    console.log('browser');

} else if (Target.Current === Target.Node) {
    console.log('node');
    
} else {
    console.log('?');
}
```

compiled with  `tsc --project tsconfig.browser.json`

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
if (1 /* Current */ === 1 /* Browser */) {
    console.log('browser');
}
else if (1 /* Current */ === 0 /* Node */) {
    console.log('node');
}
else {
    console.log('?');
}
```

compiled with   `tsc --project tsconfig.node.json`

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
if (0 /* Current */ === 1 /* Browser */) {
    console.log('browser');
}
else if (0 /* Current */ === 0 /* Node */) {
    console.log('node');
}
else {
    console.log('?');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/Morglod/tsts

Currently working on compile time transformer

```
const numbers = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ];
const result = comptime(() => {
    return numbers.reduce((total, x) => sum(total, x), 0);
});
```

to

```js
const result = (() => { return (36); })();
```